# Tense agreement and conditionals

Tags: tense, conditionals, verb-agreement

I've been struggling with tenses in conditional clauses, and I do not really understand what tenses should I use in the main clause of a conditional sentence. For instance, my answer to this question "***What would you do if you bought something disappointing on the internet?***" was the following:

---

Were it to happen, I would immediately contact the seller and explain why I ***was (were?)*** not happy with my purchase, expecting a refund or at least a replacement. In addition, I would definitely write a review, featuring what ***went*** wrong and whether I ***got*** any assistance or not.

---

The 2nd conditional has the following structure: If + past simple, would + verb. However, what about the verbs I highlighted in the main clause? Can I use past simple?

I've also found this sentence on the internet:

---

"Had I known how dull it ***was going*** to be, I would not have attended this conference."

---

In this case, I am wondering whether ***was going*** can be used in the if-clause of this type 3 conditional sentence.

I would be grateful if you could help me!)

Comment: Your sentences are correct (it's _explain why I was not happy_).

Comment: @ Kate Bunting. Thanks for replying! Does it mean that I should use past simple in cases like this in order to show that a situation is hypothetical / not real? The word “would” (…, I would immediately contact the seller and explain…) is followed by two verbs: contact and explain, so that’s my main clause. However, what about “… why I was not happy …”. I use was because it is the case of tense agreement? I am just trying to get the gist of it)

Comment: I find this really hard to explain. The conditionals are _I would contact the seller_ and _I would write a review_, but the verbs in the other clauses can be in the ordinary past simple, otherwise it would be like introducing another 'layer' of conditionality ('what would have gone wrong').